# google chrome get's a "Do you really want to start" prompt, but it's installed

Tags: snow-leopard, google-chrome

I have a mac pro with the latest mac os x, I have google chrome installed since 23 oct 2010 and still everyday when I open it mac os x ask me "Do you really want to open this software, it was downloaded from the internet 23 oct 2010" which is really annoying since it's my preferred browser.

I'm sorry that the message is in swedish but it's my fathers computer.

[image: my prompt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building up on Martin's questions and the comments.

Try to **log from your father's account** and **open Google Chrome** from there. It should ask you one last time to confirm, then, because it's an administrator's account, it will successfully **clear the quarantine flag** and you won't see it again (on either account) for Google Chrome.

Comment: I will try that, since my father doesn't care that much, he's using Safari. He is also a really stubborn mac user and says "I don't use the terminal because I have a mac" or something similar to that.

Comment: Funny. I use terminals (and a lot of other things) BECAUSE I have a Mac! Better than Windows, less frustrating than Linux.

Comment: I know, I use the terminal for all sort of things like the terminal doctor when I'm feeling sad in the morning or the terminal tetris to cheer me up! :)
Also I use it for ssh. well a lot of universe programs that work for linux works for mac in the terminal, awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Try executing from the Terminal the following command:

```
sudo xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/
```

*(it might ask you for your password, that's ok)*

This basically clears the [quarantine](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3662) flag in the metadata for the file (this is not a flag in the file itself so it doesn't get carried away when you move or copy the file to another machine)

Comment: could I do it without the sudo, i'm not the admin could I just "unmark" it?

Comment: @alvar you can try without the sudo, it won't hurt. But since you're not an admin, it might be the reason why Mac OS X cannot remove the flag when you open it.